# Damped least-square in Clojure

Tags: clojure, machine-learning, regression, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

Is there any good post and implementation in Clojure for 
Marquardt least-squares method, also known as the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm or damped least-squares?

Comment: Does it need to be in Clojure? There's a Java implementation in Apache Commons Math that you can use.

Comment: ... and another experimental one [here](https://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/wiki/LevenbergMarquardtExample).