# Can't find least square function in Clojure

Tags: python, clojure, least-squares

Can't find least square function in Clojure. I try to translate the following python code into Clojure. However, I don't see any function that is similar in Clojure. Please feel fee to comment how to implement least square in Clojure.

**problem statement; how to translate into clojure?**

> **p_lsq = leastsq(residuals_func, p_init, args=(x, y))**

**List of code (Python)**

```
    def fit_func(p, x):
        f = np.poly1d(p)
        return f(x)

    def residuals_func(p, x, y):
        ret = fit_func(p, x) - y
        return ret

    p_init = np.random.rand(3 + 1)

    # least square
    p_lsq = leastsq(residuals_func, p_init, args=(x, y))

    print('Fitting Parameters:', p_lsq[0])
```

**List of code (Clojure)**

```
(defn horner [coeffs x]
  (reduce #(-> %1 (* x) (+ %2)) (reverse coeffs)))

(defn fit_func [p x]
  (horner p x))

(defn residuals_func [p x y]
  (let [ret (- (fit_func p x) y)]))

(def p_init (take 4 (repeatedly #(rand 0.1))))
;; least square
;; Can't find similar function in clojure
;; p_lsq = leastsq(residuals_func, p_init, args=(x, y))
;;
(println (first p_lsq))
```

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343674/damped-least-square-in-clojure ? They reference Apache Commons Math: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/leastsquares.html

Comment: Besides Apache Commons Math, be sure to checkout SciCloj:  https://scicloj.github.io/pages/about/

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://dragan.rocks/articles/17/Clojure-Numerics-5-Orthogonalization-and-Least-Squares. Least Squares using neanderthal and optimized for GPU.

Comment: Incanter is a bit old. I've got some tutorial on a "more modern" way at https://github.com/scicloj/tutorials/tree/master/introductory/ols/src/ols

Comment: alex314159, AlanThompson, thanks for your suggestions. Clojure is a beutiful lisp dialect, most of the 3rd library is useful but without maintenance/update for a  long period of time. I will try to use SciCloj in ML coding. Moreover, did you try to embed R in Clojure?

Comment: @madeinQuant if you join the clojure sommunity on zulip there are active initiatives for using python and R through Clojure. https://github.com/clj-python/libpython-clj this works well

Comment: @alex314159 Thanks for your comment. For some reason, using Python 3.8 & 3.9 in virtual environment. It may be a reason why libpython-clj cannot be called in Clojure. I found python and julia may be a long term solution for scientific computing with Clojure.

Answer (score 3):

Least square method is also called linear regression.
In Python you use `numpy` and `scikitlearn` (`sklearn`).
In Cloure, you can use `incanter`.

### Python linear regression

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).reshape((-1, 1))
y = np.array([5, 9 11, 20, 24])
model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
r_sq = model.score(x, y) ## 0.9573365231259968
(model.intercept_, model.coef_[0])
# (-0.8999999999999986, 4.8999999999999995)
```

### Clojure linear regression

```
;; I install with:
;; $ lein try incanter "1.9.3"

;; basic linear regression with `incanter`
(ns linreg
  (:use [incanter.charts :only [histogram scatter-plot pie-chart add-points add-lines]]
        [incanter.core :only [view]]
        [incanter.stats :only [sample-normal linear-model]]))

(def x [1 2 3 4 5])
(def y [5 9 11 20 24])
;; linear regression
(def model (linear-model y x))
;; this plots the regression
(view (add-lines (scatter-plot x y) 
                 x (:fitted model)))

(:coefs model)
;; => (-0.8999999999999915 4.900000000000002)
(:r-square model)
;; => 0.9573365231259969
```

[image: This is the plot incanter plotted]

`model` contains much more infos:

```
{:y [5 9 11 20 24], 
:sse 10.7, 
:msr 240.1000000000002, 
:design-matrix #vectorz/array [[1.0,1.0],[1.0,2.0],[1.0,3.0],[1.0,4.0],[1.0,5.0]], 
:mse 3.5666666666666664, 
:t-probs [0.6804197120333224 0.003789007903698405], 
:adj-r-square 0.9146730462519939, 
:df [1 3], 
:coef-var #vectorz/matrix [[3.9233333333333333,-1.0699999999999998],
[-1.0699999999999998,0.3566666666666667]], 
:residuals (0.9999999999999893 0.09999999999998721 -2.800000000000015 1.299999999999983 0.3999999999999808), 
:ssr 240.1000000000002, 
:sst 250.80000000000018, 
:coefs (-0.8999999999999915 4.900000000000002), 
:f-stat 67.31775700934585, 
:r-square 0.9573365231259969, 
:f-prob 0.0037890079036982938, 
:t-tests [-0.4543754992377534 8.204739911133434], 
:x #vectorz/array [[1.0,1.0],[1.0,2.0],[1.0,3.0],[1.0,4.0],[1.0,5.0]], 
:std-errors #vectorz/vector [1.980740602232744,0.5972157622389639], 
:fitted (4.000000000000011 8.900000000000013 13.800000000000015 18.700000000000017 23.60000000000002), 
:coefs-ci ((-7.203539087942197 5.403539087942214) (2.999411453996058 6.800588546003946))}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, basically, I understood what is linear regression. I did linear regression with financial econometrics before I jump into pool of machine learning. I can embed an objective function "residuals_fun" in "leastsq" with python. However, I don't know how to optimize a similar way in Clojure. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are fitting a *linear* function, which is the case with the `horner` function that you defined, it is quite easy to fit. I am using [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) but there are many other good libraries out there too that will do the job, [EJML](http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) is my personal favourite. Here is how you can implement a function `linear-leastsq` that will fit an arbitrary *linear* function.

```
(require '[clojure.core.matrix.linear :refer [least-squares]]
         '[clojure.core.matrix :as matrix :refer [array]])

(matrix/set-current-implementation :vectorz)

(defn selector-vector
  "A vector of length n with zero in every position except for position i where it is 1"
  [n i]
  (mapv #(if (= i %) 1.0 0.0) (range n)))

(defn linear-equation-at-xy
  "Compute the left- and right-hand sides of at point (x, y)"
  [fit-func dim x y]
  (let [offset (fit-func (repeat dim 0.0) x)]
    [(map #(- (fit-func (selector-vector dim %) x) offset)
          (range dim))

     (- y offset)]))

(defn linear-leastsq [fit-func dim xy-pairs]
  (let [equations (for [[x y] xy-pairs]
                    (linear-equation-at-xy fit-func dim x y))
        A (array (map first equations))
        B (array (map second equations))
        X (least-squares A B)]
    X))
```

You can now use it with your `horner` function. Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
(defn horner [coeffs x]
  (reduce #(-> %1 (* x) (+ %2)) (reverse coeffs)))

(defn fit_func [p x]
  (horner p x))

;; Unknown function with coefficients (1.2, 4.5, -2.3)
(def unknown-function-to-estimate (partial fit_func [1.2 4.5 -2.3]))

;; Noisy observations of the unknown function
(def observation-xy-pairs (for [i (range 20)]
                            (let [x (* 0.1 i)
                                  noise (* 0.05 (- (rand) 0.5))
                                  y (+ (unknown-function-to-estimate x) noise)]
                              [x y])))

;; Estimating the coefficients of the unknown function
(linear-leastsq fit_func 3 observation-xy-pairs)
;; => #vectorz/vector [1.2110963357061681,4.455364917523691,-2.277028479451667]
```

You need these dependencies for the above approach:

```
             [net.mikera/core.matrix "0.62.0"]
             [net.mikera/vectorz-clj "0.48.0"]
```

This approach will not work if your function is *nonlinear*. In that case, you will have to resort to something like [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://users.ics.forth.gr/%7Elourakis/levmar/levmar.pdf) for nonlinear least-squares fits.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the function is used for nonlinear curve fitting. I will apply your suggestion in my machine learning code. Thank you.

Comment: @madeinQuant What function are you trying to fit? If you can be specific about that, it is easier to help.

Comment: Try to follow your comment to implement a complete runnable coding. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: thanks for your help, it seems EJML is written in JAVA and I don't see there is a wrapper for Clojure. How do I call EJML in Clojure?